# .htaccess redirect specific length random value

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

Looking for .htaccess code to make this happen.

Have:

```
http://example.com/0af31a48-562d-33d2-a75d-1931ba37a2d3
```

Need it to redirect to:

```
http://example.com/load.php?id=0af31a48-562d-33d2-a75d-1931ba37a2d3
```

The variable will always be a UUID (36 characters).

And, obviously, I need it to not redirect other things such as:

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/profile/
http://example.com/account/
http://example.com/yadda-yadda-yadda
```

So, looking for the specific length of 36 characters -- because I will never have a directory nor individual file that is 36-characters in length.

Comment: Do you want a redirect (browser url is /load.php?id=xxx-yyy) or an internal rewrite (browser url is /xxx-yyy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-f0-9-]{36})$ load.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```